# How to revert changes in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I know that Pycharm autosaves changes.

I want to know if it's possible to revert changes back to the old file if I give some input time? So is it possible to revert to, say, 8:00AM file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use local history for this. 
*Right click* on the file you want to revert, click *Local History*, then *Show History*. It's going to open a window with your current code versus previous version of your code and a side panel with the records stored.

Comment: aand then what?

Comment: @GraemeFord There's a small "U-turn to the left" icon at the very top left; click that to revert.